# Add jQuery Calendar plugin to gvNIX sample project

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

I am trying to add a jQuery calendar plugin, located at http://keith-wood.name/calendarsPicker.html
to the gvNIX project sample which uses a datePicker (I just wanted to see how it works). 
My goal is to replace this datePicker with the plugin provided by K.Wood. to have calendars other than gregorian. 
Unfortunately i did not succeed in doing so.
Here is the file i think i should modify from the gvNIX project
http://pastebin.com/5uvuDzfg

I am not a Javascript developer, so i do not know where to call the new calendar to make it work.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone need it i write what i have done. 
I implemented the Jquery plugin but to replace the current date picker i changed for dojo, because Roo using it.
 https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/date/umalqura.html I change the load-script to load the desired dojo.js files and create a copy of the datetime tag to modify it with my new picker. ( For being able to set a new tag you need to recompile the project once ). My datePicker is working well. It stored the date in gregorian any way.

In the load-script

```
 <spring:url value="/dojox/date/umalqura.js" var="umalqura_url" />
   <spring:url value="/dojox/date/umalqura/Date.js" var="umalqura_date_url" />
   <spring:url value="/dojox/date/umalqura/locale.js" var="umalqura_locale_url" />
...
<script>dojoConfig = {parseOnLoad: true}</script>
...
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">dojo.require("dijit.form.DateTextBox");</script>
```

And in the new datetime.tagx

```
<input id="_${sec_field}_id" name="${sec_field}" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.DateTextBox" datePackage = "dojox.date.umalqura" constraints="{datePattern:'EEEE dd MMMM yyyy'}" />
```

I did not figure a way to convert back the date when displaying because it's in gregorian in database.
I tried the same with a input to only register the string, but even then dojo convert it in gregorian.